# Pentaho Spoon:How to modify all the values of a column?

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new to Pentaho spoon and even after a long time of research, didn't resolve my problem:
I have a table, and want to multiply by 3 all the values of few columns.
For instance, if I have inside of a column (5, 10, 3) then it becomes (15, 30, 9).
I don't want to have a new field if it's possible, just want to replace those values.
The calculator option requires an another field and I only need one constant. Tried with Modified javaScript value, it just sets everything to zero. Can anyone help me?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Formula step to override / replace a value from an existing column. Keep in mind that for this to work, the Value Type's of both the origin and target columns must match,  INT/INT, String/String and so on.

[image]